# How to use memcpy in function that is passed a char pointer?

Tags: string, pointers, memcpy

I'm quite new to pointers in c.
Here is a snippet of code I'm working on.  I am probably not passing the pointer correctly but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
__uint16_t CCrc8();
__uint16_t process_command();


int main () {

    //command format: $SET,<0-1023>*<checksum,hex>\r\n
    char test_payload[] = "SET,1023*6e";
    process_command(test_payload);

    return 0;
}


__uint16_t process_command(char *str1) {

    char local_str[20];
    memcpy(local_str, str1, sizeof(str1));

    printf(str1);
    printf("\n");
    printf(local_str);
}
```

This results in:

```
SET,1023*6e                                                                                                       
SET,1023
```

I'm expecting both lines to be the same.  Anything past 8 characters is left off.

The only thing I can determine is that the problem is something with sizeof(str1).  Any help appreciated.

Update: I've learned sizeof(*char) is 2 on 16bit systems, 4 on 32bit systems and 8 on 64-bit systems.
So how can I use memcpy to get a local copy of str1 when I'm unsure of the size it will be?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is a compiler keyword. What you need is `strlen` from `#include <string.h>`.

The value of `sizeof` is determinated at compile time. For example `sizeof(char[10])` just means `10`. `strlen` on the other hand is a libc function that can determine string length dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` on a pointer tells you the size of the pointer itself, not of what it points to. Since you're on a 64-bit system, pointers are 8 bytes long, so your `memcpy` is always copying 8 bytes. Since your string is null terminated, you should use `stpncpy` instead, like this:

```
if(stpncpy(local_str, str1, 20) == local_str + 20) {
    // too long - handle it somehow
}
```

That will copy the string until it gets to a `NUL` terminator or runs out of space in the destination, and in the latter case you can handle it.